# User Control Page_Load running twice

Tags: c#, load, cycle

The method Page_Load is running twice in WebForms that have UserControls (UC) embebed.

I have some webforms that have user controls and others that do not have none.
In those that don't have any UC the Page_Load is running once (that's what expected). Then I put any UC in one of those WebForms and the Page_Load was executed twice.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //code when it's postback

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
               //code when it's not postback
            }
        }
```

I do expect to enter in the Page_Load but only one time.
This behavior happens everywhere (MasterPage, WebForms, child UC).

I've also tried to set AutoEventWireup="false" and attach the methods to the life cycle events but it was the same (I think it shouldn't have nothing to do with it but it was worth trying it).